# "Backend Error" when load to BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

It appears this has been a common issue, it happens now and then in my load jobs. When it happens there is no response but seems data still got loaded, I wonder what's the best thing to do in my program? can I just always ignore it or wait for some seconds and continue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can get an error when running a bigquery job, and correct handling depends on how you get that error:

- You can get an error on the HTTP request, which translates into an HTTP response code.
- You can get a job that has an `errorResult` that indicates the job failed.

In the second case, your options are easy, because you know that the job failed. If the job was a load job, it should not have modified the table. In the first case, when you get an HTTP error code that is retryable (417 timeout, 500 internalError, 503 backendError, etc), it is a bit trickier, since the error may have a communication error, and you don't know whether the server got the message successfully or not. The way to be sure is to specify your own jobId. Since job ids must be unique, you can retry sending the same job again in the event of a communication error, and you don't have to worry that it will run the same thing twice.

To reiterate: 
If you are getting an `HTTP 503` response with a `reason=backendError`, this is a connection error that indicates a temporary network condition. However, this doesn't mean that your job failed.

If you can lookup the job and the job result has an error with a `reason=internalError` but  an error message that says "Backend error. Job aborted" that means your job failed. It should be safe to retry.